# Display List<String> in textBox (Winforms)

Tags: c#, list, textbox

Noob question... I'm trying to display a List in a textbox... unfortunately, my code only displays the first element in the list...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> vegetables = new List<String>();
        vegetables.Add("tomato");
        vegetables.Add("carrot");
        vegetables.Add("celery");
        vegetables.Add("potato");

        textBox1.Text = displayMembers(vegetables);
    }

    public string displayMembers(List<String> vegetables)
    {
        foreach (String s in vegetables)
        {
            return s.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How do I get the textBox to display all of the members? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Once you `return s.ToString()`, the rest of that method stops running.
A method cannot return multiple things.

You probably want to write

```
someTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, vegetables);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [string.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
textbox1.Text = string.Join(" ", vegetables);
```

The answer was closer and easier than you thought :)

**Note:** as mentioned in the comments, this particular function has several overloads added in v4.0 of the .Net framework. If you want to see what is available for earlier versions use the `Other Versions` dropdown just under the title on the MSDN doco page.

Comment: Doesn't `string.Join` only take arrays? You'll need to call `ToArray()`.

Comment: @minitech Welcome to .NET 4.0

Comment: @sq33G: Oh, thanks for pointing that out - I always use .NET 2.0 so I'm not up to date with new features :) (Actually, though, the question doesn't mention the framework version.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the strings somehow, like

```
public string displayMembers(List<String> vegetables)
{
    return string.Join(", ", vegetables.ToArray());
}
```

or

```
public string displayMembers(List<String> vegetables)
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vegetables.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a foreach, but returning at the first element.  This is going to cause it to  just display the first element.

Instead, you probably want to do something like:

```
public string DisplayMembers(IEnumerable<String> vegetables)
{
    return String.Join(", ", vegetables);
}
```

This uses [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to "stitch together" the vegetables into a single string, which can then be shown in a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string displayMembers(List<String> vegetables)
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    foreach (String s in vegetables)
    {
        text += s.ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
    return text;
}
```