# Display list item per line in multiline Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

*First of all, when downvoting, please tell what I'm doing wrong.*

I have some items on a list. But as the users decides its count, it can have 16, 10, 12 members. Anyway, I have tried everything I could found about and none of them have worked for me. Here is one of the links that I have explored:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204078/display-liststring-in-textbox-winforms)

The only thing i was able to do, was spliting the item by spaces (or anything i want), but not skipping lines. And i have already made the text.Multiline to True.

```
foreach(var item in listMat)
{
txtGAMBIARRA.Text = String.Join(" ", listMat);
}
```

**EDIT:** Problem solved. Besides, as i Didn't know how much itens the list would have, I started increasing the height of the textbox each time the button was pressed. Hope this code helps someone:

```
private void btnAddMaterias_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
listMat.Add(txtNomeMaterias.Text);
txtGAMBIARRA.Height = txtGAMBIARRA.Height + 12;
txtGAMBIARRA.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listMat); //Here is the solution
}
```

Comment: You don't need to loop, just use the return from String.Join to set the text property of your textbox. What does the textbox look like when you use: txtGAMBIARRA.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listMat);?

Comment: Dunno what happened. I had tried something like that, but probably made another mistake. Now it's working. Anyway, is my topic right? Is there something I can do to make it easier to people understand?
And thanks buddy

Comment: Topic was ok. One improvement would have been to describe what outcome you were getting instead of just saying it didn't work.

Comment: I see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are use array you don't need to repeat that
just call Join function once without foreach

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
txtGAMBIARRA.Text = String.Join("\n", listMat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a line break too, like :
`txtGAMBIARRA.Text = String.Join("\r\n", listMat);`

Comment: You should use `System.Environment.NewLine` for new lines so that it is cross platform supported. If you are not aiming for cross-platform and are only targeting Windows, use "\r\n" as it is the correct delimiter for new lines in Windows.